# Firefox extension to dynamically change superbar icon, similar to Windows Live Messenger

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-addons, taskbar, superbar

With Windows 7's new superbar, Windows Live Messenger is now able to display your status on the bar's icon (and not on the system tray). So that got me thinking, maybe a Firefox extension could do something similar.

Therefore, here's my question to those who understand the workings and spinning wheels behind Firefox extensions: could a Firefox extension change the superbar icon to display some useful info? Does the current functionality support it?

**EDIT:**

I think my question is not really clear. I just want to know if it's theoretically possible for a Firefox addon to change the superbar icon dynamically. For instance, Windows Live Messenger changes the icon acording to your status, and Gmail Notifier Plus changes the icon according to your unread messages count.

I'm just wondering if Firefox as it is right now supports an extension with that functionality. I know that no current extensions do it, and I'm not looking for a Gmail Notifier (that was just an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the "[**Windows 7 Gmail Notifier Plus**](http://windows7center.com/news/windows-7-gmail-notifier-plus/)". It's a standalone application, not a Firefox addon, but it will display the number of unread messages in a taskbar icon.

[image]

The thumbnail preview will show you the content of unread messages:

[image]

Of course, when you click on it, Gmail will open in the default browser.

**EDIT** (after changes of the initial question):

[**WinFox**](http://www.compugeeksoftware.com/software/winfox.aspx) is not an addon as such, more an external application that brings some extended features to Firefox. However, you'll see it changes the taskbar/superbar button with some extra information:

- Frequent Items support
- Tasks support
- Pin support
- Auto-detection of the Firefox directory and user profile
- FavIcon support (downloads top fifteen favicons to your Firefox Cache directory)
- Launch Firefox by clicking on the Winfox icon
- Linking of all open Firefox windows – Sets all Firefox windows to use Winfox (only if Winfox is running)
- **Taskbar progress overlay when downloading files**
- **Number of open tabs illustrated using a taskbar icon overlay**
- Multiple Firefox profile support

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do know about this app. I was just wondering if the concept was possible, not actually looking for a gmail notifier.

Comment: Maybe you need to check Prism then: http://prism.mozilla.com/features/

Comment: Edited, as the initial question has changed.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting. Though it says nothing about extensions, it definetely gives me hope for future releases. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I strictly recommend [**WebMail Notifier**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4490) addon for Firefox.

WebMail Notifier checks your webmail accounts and notifies the number of unread emails.
You can use multiple accounts in a same host.

Currently supports
- mail.**google**.com (Gmail & Google Apps)
- mail.**yahoo**.com (yahoo.com, ymail.com, rocketmail.com, yahoo.co.jp)
- mail.**live**.com (hotmail.com, msn.com, live.com)
- www.**daum**.net (hanmail)
- www.**naver**.com
- www.**nate**.com (nate.com, empas.com)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an extension able to do exactly what you ask for. But there are some good extensions making your live with Gmail a bit easier:

**Gmail Manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1320**

- Checks multiple (gmail) account in parallel
- Able to display notification messages on new mails

**Better Gmail 2:** (link in comment do to one link per threat restriction for new members)

- A lot of enhancements on Gmail itself
- Can change the Icon displayed in the tabbar of firefox to show how many unread messages you have.

~Chris

Comment: Here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6076